# invalid application descriptor unknown namespace 4.6

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

i just overlaid flash builder 4.6 with air compiler 20
after that i was trying simple "hellow word" app but getting this errors
anyway to fix the error ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/4.6">
    <id>com.proandroidflash.HelloView.debug</id>
    <filename>HelloView</filename>
    <name>HelloView-debug</name>
    <versionNumber>0.0.1</versionNumber>

    <initialWindow>
        <content>HelloView.swf</content>
        <autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
        <fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
        <visible>true</visible>
        <softKeyboardBehavior>none</softKeyboardBehavior>
    </initialWindow>
```

Comment: `xmlns - The last segment of the namespace specifies the version of the AIR runtime required for this application to run.`
The last segment isn't the version of FlexSDK, but AIR SDK.
Your setting should be `http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/20.0`

Comment: Yes Yasuyuki was right . And the problem was fixed.